npx hardhat ignition deploy Error: Cannot find module 'cache_hardhat/.hardhat-network-instances.json'
I'm trying to use npx hardhat ignition deploy to deploy one of my modules that is inside the ignition/modules folder, however, every time I try to run the command I get this error:
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: Cannot find module 'cache_hardhat/.hardhat-network-instances.json'


Running npx hardhat clean fixes this issue for me.
